# MySQL get percentage difference from current week to last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the difference between the summers of the current week and last week. The values are all stored in a table.

I already have the individual values of the current and last week, but how do I get it in a select that these values can be offset against each other, that the difference can be displayed in percent.

The Output must show for Example: +10% or -10% depending on whether the current value is higher or lower than the last.

I tried this, but it shows always an error:

```
SELECT views_current_week / views_last_week * 100 AS difference 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(website_stats_homepage) as views_last_week  
    FROM website_stats 
    WHERE website_stats_date >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate())+6 day 
        AND website_stats_date < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate())-1 day, 
    SELECT SUM(website_stats_homepage) as views_current_week 
    FROM website_stats 
    WHERE yearweek(DATE(website_stats_date), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1)) 
website_stats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I habe made a quick sqlfiddle which should do what you want. You have to take care of 0 results cause they can crash the division.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8b906/2

To all sql cracks here. I know this can be much shorter and optimized but I thought I make it as easy to understand for a newbie as possible